# Erro de nome de app no django

Tags: django, mongodb

Na minha views, do django 1.10, tenho o código:

```html
from django.shortcuts import *
from appcrud.forms import *

def inicial(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
  form = FormCrud(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
 else:
  form = FormCrud()
 return render(request, "index.html", {"form": form})
```

O forms:

```html
from django import forms
from appcrud.models import *

class FormCrud(forms.Form):
 name = forms.CharField(max_length = 150)
 profissao = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
```

e o model:

```html
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from mongoengine import *

class Cruds(Document):
 name = StringField(max_length=150,required=True)
 profissao = StringField(max_length=150)
```

O servidor funciona normalmente mas aparece esse erro no retorno :

```html
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_app'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/inicio/
Django Version: 1.10.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_app'
Exception Location: C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts\__init__.py in render, line 49
```

Estou configurando o projeto para usar o mongodb, saberiam me responder?

Grato pela atenção!

Comment: Está parecendo que o Django 1.10 não está instalado corretamente, porque o render nem tem mais esse argumento `current_app` nessa [versão](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/shortcuts.py#L15). Minha sugestão é desinstalar o Django, e instalar novamente:

`pip uninstall -y Django`

`pip install Django --no-cache-dir`

Comment: Valeu, o fiz e deu certo!

Comment: Vou jogar o texto do comentário como resposta, pra ficar documentado pra galera que futuramente esbarrar no mesmo problema :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está parecendo que o Django 1.10 não está instalado corretamente, porque o render nem tem mais esse argumento current_app nessa versão. Desinstale o Django, e instale novamente, mas sem usar o cache, com os seguintes comandos:

```
$ pip uninstall -y Django

$ pip install Django --no-cache-dir
```